# Not able to run mysql query in java application

Tags: java, mysql

I want to backup a  MYSQL table from remote server to my local server and I have to do this in my java application. I am trying to run the follwing query to do so:

C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqldump --opt --where='1 limit 10'  -h a.b.c.d  -u root -proot remoteDB remotetable|mysql -u root -pcanada localDB

Query runs absoulutely fine when i run it through commandline but when i run it through my java application it is not able to create any backup and strangely does not show any output also.Following is the code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Process p;
    String s="C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.5\\bin\\mysqldump --opt " +
                "--where='1 limit 1'  -h a.b.c.d  -u root -proot remoteDB remoteTable|mysql -u root -pcanada " +
                "localDB";
    try {
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(s );
        p.waitFor();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line=reader.readLine();

        while (line != null) {    
            System.out.println(line);
            line = reader.readLine();
        }
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("fsff"+e);
            e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("fsdaf"+e);
            e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Please could anyone suggest why I am not run it through my java application.Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Runtime.exec is not a shell. It starts one process only, and doesn't handle input and output stream redirection, so `command1 | command2` won't work.

As a workaround you can write the command into a .cmd file and run it with cmd.exe.

Answer (score 1):

Most developers would use a library to make a MySQL query from Java instead of trying to write commands to an external program and collect the output.

See, for instance, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connector-j-usagenotes-statements.html#connector-j-examples-execute-select

Comment: I also use jdbc for excecuting the sql statements but in my case the communication is between different servers and the fastest way to do that is through the shell command i used.

Comment: Ah, ok. I wasn't sure what you were trying to do, really.